# select record by date is now in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have following table

| Item | Insert_Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 11-JAN-23 |
| B | 10-JAN-23 |

And I want to **select** records have *Insert_Date* equal Now date without write

```
select * from *My_Table* where insert_date = '11-JAN-23' ;
```

I tried

```
select * from *My_Table* where insert_date = TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) ;
```

But it doesn't work;

Comment: If the insert date is set automatically from `current_date` (or `sysdate`) then they will presumably have a non-midnight time, even if your client is not showing the time part; so you may just want `insert_date >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)`? Or  `insert_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)`, depending how the insert is done (one is system time, the other is session time, which may be different). If you can have future-dated records then you need an upper-bound too, but that seems unlikely from the name.

Comment: You can always do `SELECT *, CURRENT_DATE from...` to see what difference might be between both values.

Comment: Side notes: It is rare to use `CURRENT_DATE` in Oracle. Most of the time we work with `SYSDATE` to get the current date used in the database. If you wanted to hard code a date, you should not use a string like `'11-JAN-23'`, but a date literal like `DATE '2023-01-11'`.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type that **ALWAYS** has the components year, month, day, hour, minute and second. However, client applications (SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, etc.) often do not display the entire `DATE` and only display the date component and not the time component; that does not mean that the time component does not exist, only that you aren't seeing it with the default formatting.

This means that your date probably also has a non-midnight time component and your query is not matching on the time components. To solve it, you can select on a range:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   My_Table
WHERE  insert_date >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)
AND    insert_date <  TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

Or you can use `TRUNC`, but that would prevent you using an index on the `insert_date` column:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   My_Table
WHERE  TRUNC(insert_date) = TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE);
```

Note: To change how SQL*Plus and SQL Developer format dates in your current session, you can use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE Insert_Date = CAST( GET_DATE() AS Date)
```

Comment: `GET_DATE` is not a valid Oracle function.